# x-axis rotation on a 6-subplots

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I am a bit stuck with the matplotilb subplot tools. Here's what I'm trying to do: I want 6 subplots displaying time-series of data. My data look like this (t1,t2,h1,h2...,time), as lists.

My code is currently as follows:

```
fields={0:'Air temperature (K)',1:'Specific humidity',2:'Sea Surface 
temperature (K)',3:'Surface air pressure (hPa)',4:'Wind (m.s-1)'}


fieldsfoam={0:t1,1:h1,2:sst1,3:p1,4:w1,5:astd1}
fieldsostia={0:t2,1:h2,2:sst2,3:p2,4:w2,5:astd2}


plt.close()

f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4),(ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex='col')
ax={1:ax1,2:ax2,3:ax3,4:ax4,5:ax5,6:ax6}
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(-3,3))

for i in range (1,7):

    ax[i].plot(unit.num2date(time,'hours since 1970-01-01 00:00:00',
 unit.CALENDAR_STANDARD),fieldsfoam[i-1])     
    ax[i].plot(unit.num2date(time,'hours since 1970-01-01 00:00:00',
unit.CALENDAR_STANDARD),fieldsostia[i-1],color='r')
    plt.setp(ax[i].get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, fontsize=0)
```

I also try with

```
 plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=45)
```

but I got the same (long) error:

```
plt.setp(ax[i].get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, fontsize=10)
    File "/usr/local/sci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2614, in get_xticklabels
    self.xaxis.get_ticklabels(minor=minor))
   File "/usr/local/sci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1161, in get_ticklabels
    return self.get_majorticklabels()
  File "/usr/local/sci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1145, in get_majorticklabels
    ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
  File "/usr/local/sci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1244, in get_major_ticks
    numticks = len(self.get_major_locator()())
  File "/usr/local/sci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/dates.py", line 802, in __call__
    self.refresh()
  File "/usr/local/sci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/dates.py", line 819, in refresh
    dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
  File "/usr/local/sci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/dates.py", line 564, in viewlim_to_dt
    return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
  File "/usr/local/sci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/dates.py", line 311, in num2date
    return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
  File "/usr/local/sci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/dates.py", line 214, in _from_ordinalf
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix)
ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

If I do not rotate my dates, they overlap.
Everything works fine, except for the rotation part.

If anybody had any ideas about the mistake(s) I'm probably doing, it would be useful!

Thanks
Flo

Comment: This is a wild guess (since you didn't post a comlete and runable example and also no complete error trace): the error has nothing to do with the rotation, but comes from trying to set `fontsize=0`. A fontsize of 0 does not make sense at all. For this the error message would also make sense (saying that the fontsize has to be >= 1).

Comment: Hi, 
I can't post a complete example because my data are quite big and I did not want to create a couple of random lists because I thought the problem could come from my data...
I edit my question with the complete error...

Comment: if you think *the problem could come from your data* and you don't provide your data, how should anyone be able to help you?

Comment: When I said could come from the datas, I mean could come from the facts that I have lists... My problem may be that I'm dealing with dates, so I have to use formatter tools. If I give 6 lists of random floats values, there won't be representative of what I really have.
I was just wondering if there was some silly and obvious mistake (for some of you) that I couldn't see or if there was a tool I should / should not use. Sorry if I bothered you.